# How to dynamically create and populate a local temp table (when the table headers are unknown)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently using code similar to the following:

```
SET @Query = 'SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM MyTable'
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Obviously, this does not work. Until now, I have been getting around this problem by using global temporary tables within my dynamic sql. However, this is not an option once the stored procedure is released to users, as their global temp tables would conflict with one another.

How might I get around this issue? I must specify that the structure of the table `MyTable` is unknown, so creating the temp table outside of the dynamic sql is (presumably?) not an option.

**Edit:** Apologies if I was not specific enough with exactly what I am trying to achieve - I thought it would be best to keep this question as relevent to the actual issue as possible.

Obviously, the string that I am trying to execute is not fixed. It is instead constructed so that the table, from which the data is being retrieved, may be specified. Although still not overly complex, the actual query string that I am using is more along the lines of

```
@Query = CONCAT('SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM ', @Environment, '.[schema].', @Table)
```

Hopefully this sheds more light on the problem?

Comment: This is way too broad and unclear as to what your goal is. Local temp tables would be fine if each user activating the proc had a different spid and the table got dropped at the end of their operation.

Comment: Yes, local tables would work fine... but you can't create local tables dynamically?

Comment: Why do you think you need dynamic sql? From what you posted you wouldn't need dynamic sql. Then you wouldn't have scope issues with your temp tables.

Comment: @J.Chapman Sure you can. Inside your query put '; SELECT * FROM #temp'

Comment: Or maybe you need to share a higher view of what you are really trying to accomplish. This could very well be an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @SeanLange I smell an XY Problem.

Comment: I also guess it's an XY problem. in addition OP can learn a bit more about temp tables, table variables and how to pass a dataset as a SP parameter

Comment: If that's all you need to do, why the dynamic sql?

Answer (score 0):

Few points:
1. If you want to store the output of dynamic sql into temp table, you need to create the temp table structure first(with CREATE TABLE #TEMP script) and then you can insert data by doing something like below:

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

This will populate data into temp table with all properties of local temp table.

2. Seeing your query, it does not look like you have a need of dynamic sql unless you are forming some clause like where clause dynamically.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: In order to create the temporary table, I would need to know the structure of the data that I am trying to insert into it. Unfortunately, this is not the case. I have edited my origional question - hopefully this makes it more obvious what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, seeing your edit, what do you plan to do after the data comes(lets say) in #TEMP?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something like this:

```
declare @query nvarchar(4000) = '
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[temp]'') AND type in (N''U''))
begin 
       drop table temp
end

Select top 2 * 
into temp 
from sys.databases
'
exec sp_executesql @query

Select * from temp
```

With Select into you don't need to know the structure of your query:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Just as an idea.